# Make seperate toggle buttons work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

i have some info containers that show some infos in the beginning, when clicked on close they should be hiding and a info button should show up to make them display again on click. Throughout the page there are similar info fields and buttons. And i only wanna show and hide the ones clicked on and not globaly all of them.

Has anybody an idea how to make this function. Here's my code.

```
<div class="it-con">
   <div class="mess-text">
       <span class="x-btn">&#10005;<br></span>
       <h4>Headline</h4>
       <br>
       <p>Some Info</p>
   </div>
   <div class="toggle">
        <div class="inf-btn">Info</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery i came up with so far.

```
$(".it-con .x-btn").click(function(e){
     $(this).closest('.mess-text').fadeOut(100);    
})
```

but don't know how to make the inf-btn to display. Nor how to make the mess-text reappear.

Help is really appreciated.

: )

Answer (score 0):

You can just make one button that toggles visibility like this:

```
<div class="it-con">
   <div class="mess-text">
       <span class="x-btn">&#10005;<br></span>
   </div>
   <div class="toggle">
       <h4>Headline</h4>
       <br>
       <p>Some Info</p>  
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".it-con .x-btn").click(function(e){
    info = $(this).parent().next('.toggle')
    info.toggle();
    if (info.is(":visible")) {
      $(this).html('HIDE');  
    } else {
      $(this).html('SHOW');    
    }
})
```

Comment: I think i need this button also to toggle with the text. When the text is shown the button should be invisible. When the text-container is invisible i want the button to be visible.

Comment: But if the hide button is invisible, how do you hide the text?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/mkwaskyr/)?

***The code:***

```js
$(".inf-btn").click(function (e) {
    $(this).siblings('.mess-text').slideToggle();
    $(this).text(function (i, text) {
        return text === "Hide info" ? "Show info" : "Hide info";
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="it-con">
    <button class="inf-btn">Hide info</button>
    <div class="mess-text">
         <h4>Headline</h4>

        <br>
        <p>Some Info</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="it-con">
    <button class="inf-btn">Hide info</button>
    <div class="mess-text">
         <h4>Headline</h4>

        <br>
        <p>Some Other Info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would have been actually a good idea. But i actually sometimes have two buttons that always are supposed to be visible as long as the text is invisible.  So they're should be outside the text-container i guess. And i don't know how to make the outside button make the text-container reappear.

Comment: The buttons never dissapear with this code, they are outside the text-wrapper. The buttons call a slideToggle() function over the text, to make it appear and dissappear while the button is always visible.

Comment: Both solutions posted do exactly what you're describing.